# how to allocate 4-8 MB aligned DMA Linux

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, dma

I"m using Fedora 14 and i"m building a driver for a PCI switch.
for that switch I need to allocate 8MB of DMA memory (I can handle 2*4MB) but I need it aligned to memory size, for example, if its 8MB then the first 23 bits of the base address should be 0.

how do i do that?

Comment: I found a way to allocate 2mb aligned DMA. to do this I allocate 4MB and in it there must be 2MB that is aligned to it's size.

If there is a way to increase the maximum dma to allocate to 8mb this should solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

`__get_free_pages` can allocate up to 4MB, allocated on the allocation size.
So you can allocate two 4MB blocks, each aligned on 4MB.

You can't get 8MB aligned this way.
During boot, if you allocate 3*4MB, very likely the blocks will be contiguous, so either the first and second, or the second and third, would be 8MB aligned. But I wouldn't rely on it.

Notice that you should do this early during boot, in any case. Otherwise, it's very likely that memory is fragmented and you won't be able to get your memory.

Answer (score 0):

`__get_free_pages` gave me maximum 4MB, but it was aligned to page size only (4k).

I've managed to allocate 16MB DMA using `pci_alloc_consistent` and there is at least 8mb aligned to 8mb. That solved my problem.